# Compiling Freeswitch source from master branch with mod_opus on debian jessie failed

Tags: freeswitch

make freeswitch master failed with below output:

```
making all mod_opus
make[4]: Entering directory '/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/codecs/mod_opus'
Makefile:884: *** You must install libopus-dev to build mod_opus.  Stop.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod/codecs/mod_opus'
Makefile:645: recipe for target 'mod_opus-all' failed
make[3]: *** [mod_opus-all] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src/mod'
Makefile:555: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/freeswitch/src'
Makefile:2948: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/freeswitch'
Makefile:1346: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

If I understand it correctly is asking for libopus-dev which already have installed.
This is apt-cache output:

```
root@wecall:/usr/local/src/freeswitch# apt-cache policy libopus-dev
libopus-dev:
  Installed: 1.1-18~1-jessie+1
  Candidate: 1.1-18~1-jessie+1
  Version table:
 *** 1.1-18~1-jessie+1 0
        500 http://files.freeswitch.org/repo/deb/freeswitch-1.6/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.1-2 0
        500 ftp://mir2.ovh.net/debian/ jessie/main amd64 Packages
```

This is locations where libopus-dev installed:

```
root@wecall:/usr/local/src/freeswitch# dpkg --listfiles libopus-dev
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig/opus.pc
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.a
/usr/include
/usr/include/opus
/usr/include/opus/opus_defines.h
/usr/include/opus/opus_types.h
/usr/include/opus/opus_multistream.h
/usr/include/opus/opus.h
/usr/share
/usr/share/doc
/usr/share/doc/libopus-dev
/usr/share/doc/libopus-dev/copyright
/usr/share/doc/libopus-dev/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libopus.so
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you install the libopus, please make clean and re-call the script ./configure. Then make it again.

Willen

Answer (score 0):

You need to comment following lines in source and then recompile again:

```
vi freeswitch/src/mod/codecs/mod_opus/Makefile
# Comment line 889 & 890
#install: error 
#all: error
```